# When i press a back button on my first fragment, the app should exit

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the below code to bring back the home screen fragment from next fragment by  pressing back button. Now i want to know how to exit from the app when i click back button from home fragment.

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
      FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.container, homefragment, LearnSourastraUtils.HOME_FRAGMENT_TAG);
      ft.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true); 
getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in Activity in which you are adding or replacing fragments

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
       finish();
 } else {                   
  getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a variable check position of fragment like:

```
int position;
```

and check position in onBackPressed if position =0 then exit the app:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(position!=0)
  { //Do something
  }
  else finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i do :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    if(fragment_num != 0)
    {
        displayView(0);
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

but you should define fragment_num  variable as a global var to can get it from here.
put this in your activity that has fragments , this code works for me , and when i tap back button , it goes to fragments num 0 , and if you are in that fragment , the app will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I already suggested this as an answer in your previous post, but I'll post it here again.

In the section where you change your fragment, do something like this:

```
currentFragment = fragmentToDisplay;
```

Now in your onBackPressed, at the way top, add the following:

```
if (currentFragment == homefragment){
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
    getActivity().finish(); 

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

> public boolean moveTaskToBack (boolean nonRoot)
>
> Added in API level 1 Move the task containing this activity to the
>   back of the activity stack. The activity's order within the task is
>   unchanged.
>
> Parameters nonRoot    If false then this only works if the activity is
>   the root of a task; if true it will work for any activity in a task.
>   Returns If the task was moved (or it was already at the back) true is
>   returned, else false.

Please check life cycle process

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. You should just pop the the last entry from the backstack, and not do a frag transaction on pressing the back key. Change your code to this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```